# The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource

Tags: node.js, lookback

```
Error: Cannot call users.find(). The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!
    at throwNotAttached (F:\PPL\Laundry\api.lb\node_modules\loopback\lib\persisted-model.js:71:11)
    at Function.find (F:\PPL\Laundry\api.lb\node_modules\loopback\lib\persisted-model.js:259:5)
    at module.exports (F:\PPL\Laundry\api.lb\common\models\users.js:11:11)
    at F:\PPL\Laundry\api.lb\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:251:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at defineModels (F:\PPL\Laundry\api.lb\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:229:23)
    at setupModels (F:\PPL\Laundry\api.lb\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:197:3)
    at execute (F:\PPL\Laundry\api.lb\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\executor.js:40:3)
    at bootLoopBackApp (F:\PPL\Laundry\api.lb\node_modules\loopback-boot\index.js:154:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\PPL\Laundry\api.lb\server\server.js:23:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) DataSource:

```
{
  "mysqlDB": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "url": "",
    "database": "databse",
    "password": "",
    "name": "mysqlDB",
    "user": "root",
    "connector": "mysql"
   }
}
```

MySQL defaults to port **3306**

2)Config Model: **model-config.json**

```
"users": {
    "dataSource": "mysqlDB",
    "public": true
  }
```

And remove inner function in **Model**

like :

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Users) {

};
```